# how to make realtime chat app using firestore with recyclerview

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

this app uses to store vendors and users and chat between them. I want to make an android chat app using recycleview and firebase firestore but the problem is that recycle view doesn't update properly so how to do that. data also get but after sending time not show instantly message I want to go back after that show message and also message not show proper order from firestore so how to do it.
message history also wants perfectly. please help to solve this problem this is my code.

This is the structure of the firebase firestore database

I want a simple solution to how to make a real-time chat app with firestore and recyclerview...

[image: first image]
[image: second image]
[image: third image]

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **350** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: What exactly in all these lines of code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: hey @AlexMamo i have changed my question i want a simple solution to how to do real-time chat app using firestore and recyclerview

Comment: If you are interested, I have explained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb)** how you can create a complete and functional Firestore Chat App.

Answer (score 1):

Look bro -
If u want to get real-time update using firestore then add
Snapshotlister then u get real time update..
2nd things that
If you want to make chat app .then
Don't go with fireStore because  ur read and write count ll become increased
Due to this Ur Firebase bill will be high.may be u can't afford it.
And also it is not recommend to use firestrore to making chat app.

Comment: yes I know all thing but I want a temporary solution for making a chat app because its a dummy chat app

Comment: Why isn't it recommended to use Firestore to make a chat app? It's exactly one of its main use cases.

Comment: Bcoz of billing of Firebase its cost of too much like firestore billing count as document hit. In the scenario of chat app user will send the message continuously then document count is increase repeatdly that increase ur bill too much